# Flatten observations over time into single row

Tags: python, pandas

How do I flatten these parameters from this:

```
          PARAM_A           PARAM_B              PARAM_C
0        0.020087          0.689655             0.001172
1        0.083058          0.336634             0.012243
2        0.108894          0.320423             0.022950
```

The row indices are periods of observation. Into something like this:

```
  PARAM_A_0  PARAM_A_1  PARAM_A_2  PARAM_B_0  PARAM_B_1  PARAM_B_2 ...
?  0.020087   0.083058   0.108894   0.689655   0.336634   0.320423 ...
```

I put a `?` in the index because I'm not sure what it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way using `stack`

```
s=df.stack()
s.index=s.index.map('{0[1]}_{0[0]}'.format)
s=s.to_frame().T
s
   PARAM_A_0  PARAM_B_0  PARAM_C_0    ...      PARAM_A_2  PARAM_B_2  PARAM_C_2
0   0.020087   0.689655   0.001172    ...       0.108894   0.320423    0.02295
[1 rows x 9 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `df.stack()`, it stacks the columns on each other giving you a series. You can transpose the series to get a row afterward.